# PHP Files Not Updating

Tags: php

I HAve a Website http://fbtricks.cf/
And It's Hosted in Hostinger.in

M Using PHP Extension, Because M Using a Common Header and Footer For All Files.

- The Problem Is, I Have Made Changes to The Header and Footer. But Still The CHANGE is Not Reflecting in All Files. :(

And It's Not Just an ISsue in My Browser, But in Every Browser, The Old Header and Footer is Displaying Except in The Index File.

I THINK THAT, MAYBE IT"S HAPPENING BECAUSE THE SERVER HAS CACHED THE FILES.

Plz Provide Me With a Solution, as It's a Serious Issue For Me and My Website and Also For Website Visitors.

header file Link - http://fbtricks.cf/header.php

Comment: Why Do You Capitalize Every Word Like This? It's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this .htaccess file can override the global settings in Hostinger.

**.htaccess:**

```
<filesMatch "\.(html|htm|js|css)$">
    FileETag None
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
       Header unset ETag
       Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
       Header set Pragma "no-cache"
       Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
    </ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```